# Rationale for the sum of an empty vector to return 0

Tags: r, vector, sum, na

Disclaimer: I am **not** asking how to bypass this behaviour, but rather would like explanation as to why this is the default behaviour.

I came across a behaviour of the `rowSums()` and `sum()` functions in R whose rationale escapes my understanding.

Let `mat` a matrix whose rows have i) no `NA`, ii) one `NA`, iii) only `NA`'s, iv) only `0`:

```r
> mat <- matrix(c(1:8, rep(NA, 4), rep(0, 3)), ncol=3, byrow=T)
> mat
[,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA
[5,]    0    0    0
```

Computing the row sums with `rowSums()` gives:

```r
> rowSums(mat)
[1]  6 15 NA NA  0
```

Fair enough, if we have any `NA` in the row, it'll return `NA`.
Let's tell `rowSums()` to remove `NA`'s in the calculation:

```r
> rowSums(mat, na.rm=T)
[1]  6 15 15  0  0
```

We see that a `NA`-only vector has a sum of zero if `na.rm=T`, which is confirmed by doing the sum of an empty vector.

```r
> sum(c())
[1] 0
```

I cannot understand the rationale behind returning zero for the sum of an empty vector (following `na.rm=T`). Is it an arbitrary decision?

I was expecting the sum of an empty vector to return `NA`, for two reasons:

- It would make the distinction between a `NA`-only vector input, and a `0`-only vector input.
  This seems fundamental to me as `0` means "no signal", and `NA` means "no measure/not possible".
- Assessment of the argument type:
  The `sum()` function blindly assumes that an empty vector is somehow of type *numeric* since it returns zero. Why?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but from ?sum:
"NB: the sum of an empty set is zero, by definition."
So, I guess the answer is "Because we say so." :)

Comment: And similarly, the product of an empty set is 1 (neutral element of the multiplication).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0 is the only sensible value. First off, because it's the [neutral element of addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element). Mathematically, this is all the justification we need, really.<sup>1</sup>

But secondly, your reasoning doesn’t make sense:

> - It would make the distinction between a `NA`-only vector input, and a `0`-only vector input.

We are talking about an *empty* vector. It’s neither `NA`-only nor `0`-only. So, right out of the door, this reason doesn’t apply here.

> - The `sum()` function blindly assumes that an empty vector is somehow of type *numeric* since it returns zero.

The `sum()` function does no such thing:

```
typeof(sum(integer(0L)))
# [1] "integer"
```

What you are observing is that *`c()` is of type `numeric`*. This is unrelated to `sum()`.

---

<sup>1</sup> There are two potential objections to this:

1. Even in mathematics, it’s merely a convention in certain domains. Yes, but this convention is *extremely* widespread, with no real alternatives, and exists for good reasons because it makes large swathes of mathematics consistent and simple.
2. Why do we care about mathematics? And again the reason comes back to the fact that the mathematical convention make sense, and the consistency it provides permeates into our code. Put differently, the fact that the sum of an empty vector is 0 *drastically* simplifies most code. If this weren’t the case, we’d have to special-case empty vectors almost anywhere a sum is computed.

Comment: That's true, the vector is empty so the distinction between an initial 0-only or NA-only input does not matter here. I just had my application in mind when writing this. Note that `typeof(c())` probably makes more sense to showcase that the type of `c()` is numeric.